# Javascript Date to IS8601 format?

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

I am learning javascript and I am trying to figure out if there is a simple way to convert a standard formatted Date to [ISO8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD). 
Advices?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard formatted Date"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean something like the IETF standard format as CMS pointed out: Thu, 15 Oct 2009 12:30:00 GMT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean by *"standard formatted date"* a date string in the IETF standard format (i.e.: 'Thu, 15 Oct 2009 12:30:00 GMT') that is acceptable by the [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) function and by the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor, you can parse the date and write a simple helper function to return an ISO8601 date, using a Date object as input:

```
function ISODateString(d){

  function pad(n){
    return n<10 ? '0'+n : n;
  }

  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
    + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
    + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
    + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
    + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
    + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
}


var d = new Date('Thu, 15 Oct 2009 12:30:00 GMT');
console.log(ISODateString(d)); // 2009-10-15T12:30:00Z
```

Comment: This seems the clear and simple solution I've been looking for. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 5):

I use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/) for all my non-human dating needs.

Answer (score 0):

From Date to ISO8061:

```
var d = new Date();
d.toJSON(); // return "2013-09-23T07:42:18.730Z"
```

From ISO8061 to Date:

```
var ms = Date.parse('2013-09-23T07:42:18.730Z');
var date = new Date(ms);
```